# How can I remove commits of a file between two revision numbers?

Tags: git

I have a git repo in which I commit my apk builds for Android. I'm guessing that is a bad idea but I did it because sometimes I need to go back to a certain apk version to test and rebuilding isn't an option as gradle dependencies are often no longer available.

So now my repo is 2 gigs and I need to make some space. The last time this happened I did something wrong and lost a bit of history, so I want to make sure I do it right this time as I'm not really in a hurry like last time.

Basically I commit my apk every time I build it and release it even to beta users. I would like to remove all non production apks from the history of my repo. So basically I want to remove all apks between revision xyz and revision abc. I want to keep everything before xyz and everything after abc. I should mention the apk has the same file name always and this repo is exclusively only used for the apk file.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the commit history is like `A-B-xyz-C-D-abc-E-F<----master`.

```
git branch backup_master master
git rebase --strategy=recursive -X theirs --onto B abc master
```

`xyz C D abc` are removed from the history, which is expected to be like `A-B-E'-F'` now. Since apk is a binary file, there is always conflict during such rebase. This is why we need `--strategy=recursive -X theirs` here. After rebase is done, you could do some check to see if the apk in `E` and the apk in `E'` are the same. If `E` is okay, we can be sure the commits afterwards are okay too.

```
git rev-parse E:<apk_path>
git rev-parse E':<apk_path>
```

If the two outputs are the same, all is okay now.

If we don't use `--strategy=recursive -X theirs`, rebase is paused when applying `E` due to conflict. If this happens, run the following commands to finish the rebase.

```
git checkout E -- apk_path
git add apk_path
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: I think this worked. I had issues pushing the changes but since the repo is just used by me I deleted the remote one and pushed it again. Thanks.